# How do I call a route from vue file?

Tags: php, symfony

In my controller I have a route that exports a JSON Response with Budget objects (id + name).

**BudgetsController.php**

```
#[Route('budgets', name: 'api.budgets')]
public function findBudgets(BudgetRepository $budgets): JsonResponse
{
    return new JsonResponse($budgets->findAll());
}
```

My question is, how do I call this route so I can create a `select` (dropdown) field on my .vue page containing all the budget names (and their ID as the `option` value)?

Comment: Why not use a common AJAX request? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have thought about that, but I don't have AJAX experience. Where can I read about that to make a simple request? @NicoHaase

Comment: There are tons of tutorials available on the internet to learn AJAX. If you haven't tried anything, check out any of them

Comment: You could start from the w3schools website, they have examples using xhr

Comment: I don't know how you front-end is, but you could use fetch() (vanilla js) or Axios (you could find lot of informations about this library). The route should be the base uri of your back-end with /budgets